# strange behavior of GHashTable in GLib

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, glib

i am writing an program like:

```
typedef struct _DsSourceBin {
  gint        index;
  gchar      *name;
  GstElement *bin;
  GstElement *src;
  gchar      *uri;
  GHashTable *config;
} DsSourceBin;

typedef struct _StreamContext {
  guint       num_source{0};
  DsSourceBin src_bin[16];
  GstElement *streammux;
  GstElement *sink;
  GstElement *primary_detector;
  GstElement *nvtile;
  GstElement *nvosd;
  gchar      *config_file;
} StreamContext;
```

when using a `StreamContext`, i wrote: `StreamContext ctx;`, so in gdb, in my understand, i should have seen the full structure of the `DsSourceBin` array (because of implicit initialization?), but i'm not:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3PBP.png)

Unless i change my code like:
`GHashTable *config = NULL;`
why is this happening? Is there any clue like C standard, or lib rules that i missed?

I also tried deleting `GHashTable*` and i can get the full structure of `StreamContext`:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO2SD.png)

Comment: Why do you think it's the code and not your tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i work it out, this is actually the behavior of vscode C++ debugger: when using the release mode of GLib, some debug info will not available, so vscode will not show all of them, but there are little info that do exists, so using GDB in the debug console of VSCode will find the info I need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).